# Nusoap php request is empty

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I am trying to populate a request using nusoap and php 5.3.  Everything I have tried has left me with an empty request.  Where am I going wrong?

This is what i'm trying to create…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance">
  <soap:Header>
    <CardSoapHeader xmlns="https://service.pct.com/">
      <Username>username</Username>
      <Password>password</Password>
      <Account>account</Account>
    </CardSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <AddressLookup xmlns="https://service.pct.com/">
      <request>
        <CompanyReferenceGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000</CompanyReferenceGuid>
        <AdminUserIdentifier>00000000-0000-0000-0000</AdminUserIdentifier>
        <MirrorRequest>false</MirrorRequest>
        <Surname>surname</Surname>
        <Postcode>postcode</Postcode>
        <HouseName>1</HouseName>
        <AuthenticateCardApplicants>false</AuthenticateCardApplicants>
      </request>
    </AddressLookup>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my php…

```
<?php
require_once('./soap/lib/nusoap.php');

$client = new nusoap_client('https://uat.service.efirstcard.co.uk/v3_1/SignupService.asmx?wsdl', 'wsdl');
$requestArray[] = array(
/*                      
'CardSoapHeader' => array('Username' => 'username',                             
'Password' => 'password',                                           
'Account' => 'account'),
*/                                                              
'CompanyReferenceGuid' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000',                        
'AdminUserIdentifier' => '00000000-0000-0000-0000',                     
'MirrorRequest' =>'false',                      
'Surname' =>'surname',                      
'Postcode' =>'postcode',                        
'HouseName' =>'1',                      
'AuthenticateCardApplicants' =>'false');

// Doc/lit parameters get wrapped
$result = $client->call('AddressLookup', array('request' => array($requestArray)));

echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
?>
```

And this is what it generates…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns9681="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <AddressLookup xmlns="https://service.pct.com/">
      <request></request>
    </AddressLookup>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```